# How can I make a bouncy body bounce lower off another body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a game using Box2D in libGDX. I have a "wall" object which is a static `ChainShape` body set around the screen, some "balls" which are dynamic `CircleShape` bodies and negative gravity. The balls should be very bouncy, so I set a big `1.1f` restitution to them, but the wall shouldn't, and even if I set the wall's restitution to zero, balls bounce off it too high. I need something like setting negative restitution to the wall so the balls will bounce higher off each other and lower off the wall. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the balls restitution in the preSolve callback, according to the body it is colliding with?

Comment: @noone yep, I tried this. That worked not every time the ball hit the wall. Now I tried to scale linear velocity of the ball after collision and it helped. But I still think there's a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could have 2 variables storing the direction of movement in both axis.
Example:

`double xDirection,yDirection;`

then in your update method you can add it to the current position of the object.
now if you want it to bounce off a surface you multiply it's value by -1.This will reverse the direction of the object.
For example, say a ball is moving at a speed of 2units in the x-axis.
When the ball hits the edge, xDirection will be multiplied by -1. Now xDirection is -2. Thus, the direction of the ball is reversed.
However, this will make the ball bounce back at the same speed. In order to fix this, you can multiply xDirection with 0.5.Now if we were to multiply the xDirection of the ball with 0.5, xDirection would be -1. Thus, the ball would move slower. Using the same concept you can make the ball move faster by multiplying by 1.5 instead of 0.5. And, you can do this with yDirection too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I understood I should manually edit linear velocity of the ball on firing the collision event, and there's no way to solve this with Box2D features? There's no anything related to Box2D in your answer though.

Comment: Sorry user3762140, I have very little experience with Box2D but when you said bounce I thought of this.